# How to retain wins or losses and reset the remaining variables in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code which outputs wins/losses if I win my game. I need to then reset everything once I win/lose, but maintain my win/loss count each time I reset:

```
$("#mercury-planet").click(function() {
    var count = parseInt($("#counter").val());
    console.log(count);
    count += parseInt($("#mercuryHidden").val());
    $("#counter").val(count);
    if($("#counter").val() === randomNumber){
        wins++;
        $("#wins").html = "Wins: " + wins;
        //Win counter
        var winCount = parseInt($("#winCounter").val());
        winCount += parseInt($("#mercuryHidden").val());
        $("#winCounter").val(winCount + winCount + 1);//.val() -->needs to be updated
        alert("You won the game!!")
    }
    else if($("#counter").val() > randomNumber){
        losses++;
        $("#losses").html = "Losses: " + losses;
        //Loss counter
        var lossCount = parseInt($("#lossCounter").val());
        lossCount += parseInt($("#mercuryHidden").val());
        $("#lossCounter").val(lossCount - lossCount + 1);//.val() -->needs to be updated
        alert("You lost the game!!")
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If you wan to retain winCount and lossCount well just move these variable declaration outside of the click handler function.

Comment: Please attach your existing html markup and js code in a fiddle